# Monero balance lost?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have an issue: my balance in GUI went to zero and I do not understand how to back it up. Explanation:

I was about to send a tx but before I could confirm with my password, my PC crashed. I restarted the GUI but balance was 0.
My guess is that the tx is unspent but out of the wallet interface anyway. I tried to backup the entire wallet with seed but it didn't change anything.
Anything I can do? And do tx reverse automatically if not signed after a certain amount of time?
Please note that no transaction is showing in the wallet, so I do not have any Tx ID

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's good news that you see no transactions.  If you saw that your funds were spent, that would be bad.  If you see no transactions, then the wallet file is probably corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a corrupted file.
Make sure your daemon is synced 100% and create a new wallet, using your mnemonic seed.

Maybe, create the new wallet files in another location than the original.

```
monero-wallet-cli --restore-from-seed --generate-new-wallet new-filename \
    --electrum-seed "your seed words..." \
    --mnemonic-language English \
    --password "some optional new password"
```